# Android - Dynamic Spinner

Tags: java, android, layout, dynamic, spinner

I have a Game View which triggers 1 Dialog, from here a second Dialog is triggered.

Within this second dialog, I have 2 buttons and 1 spinner. The issue I am having is getting a spinner to appear within my view, with dyamic data.

Essentially, I need to spinner to popup when the button is clicked on and list all the relevent data. I have 3 different ArrayLists (1 String and 2 integers), which hold sepearte information which will need to be dynamically added to each spinner choice e.g.

```
pt1 -   ArrayLists1
        ArrayLists2
        ArrayLists3
pt2 -   ArrayLists1
        ArrayLists2
        ArrayLists3
```

Spinner XML layout code:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <Button android:text="@string/attack" 
            android:id="@+id/Attack" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button android:text="@string/useitem" 
            android:id="@+id/UseItemBtn" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Spinner android:text="@string/useitem"
            android:id="@+id/UseItemSpin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    <Button android:text="@string/equipweapon" 
            android:id="@+id/EquipWeapon" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code that I am currently using to trigger the click of the spinner (the log here is triggered):

```
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

@Override
public void onClick(View clicked)
{
    if(clicked.getId() == R.id.UseItemBtn)
    {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.UseItemSpin);

        ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayList1.add("test item the first one");
        arrayList1.add("really long list item - section 2 goes here - finally section 3");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String> (context,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,arrayList1);
        // APP CURRENTLY CRASHING HERE
        spinner.setAdapter(adp);
       //Set listener Called when the item is selected in spinner
       spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
       {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3) 
            {
                String city = "The city is " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), city, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
    BattleRun.show();
}
```

How can I add the dynamic spinner on this click. On top of this when the spinner is clicked, ideally I would like a submit button within the actual spinner so they can flick through the choices before selecting (which should be visible at all times).

Finally, when the item has been selected in the spinner and submitted the previous dialog will automatically refresh with the new data (this I can do easy enough).

If you require any more code snippets please let me know, any help or guidence would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
L & L Partners

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use this code to populate your spinner with the string array list -

```
    public void onClick(View clicked){
    if(clicked.getId() == R.id.Attack){
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.UseItem);

      //Sample String ArrayList
        ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>();

        arrayList1.add("Bangalore");
        arrayList1.add("Delhi");
        arrayList1.add("Mumbai");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,arrayList1);
        spinner.setAdapter(adp);

        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       //Set listener Called when the item is selected in spinner
       spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
       {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long arg3) 
            {
                String city = "The city is " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), city, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        //BattleRun.dismiss();
        Log.d("Item","Clicked");

    }
}
```

This code will go inside your layout xml file -

```
<!-- Add onClick attribute on this button -->
<Button android:text="@string/attack" 
        android:id="@+id/Attack" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick" />
<Spinner android:text="@string/useitem" 
        android:id="@+id/UseItem" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />
<Button android:text="@string/equipweapon" 
        android:id="@+id/EquipWeapon" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Note that you are not adding onClick inside the xml file. That's why your onClick function is not getting called.
You can also use the string-array in strings.xml file for using static list.

Comment: I new to the whole android and java development. Basically, I have a dialog. This has a button (which works) and a 2 x spinner. I need it so that when the spinner is clicked, it is loaded up with the format i have show in my questions. This will consist of data from 3 different ArrayLists (1 x string & 2 x ints). To sum up the main issue I am having is detecting the click of the spinner button then creating it with the dynamic content. Thanks

Comment: Hey .. was the answer helpful ... Did you got what you needed in your application .

Comment: Hi, Just trying to implement you above fix, however getting a few errors. Your 3rd line of code reffering to the ArrayAdapter, I am getting an error saying it is undefined. Also, cannot detect setOnItemSelectedListener. Shall I use setOnItemClickListener instead? Thanks

Comment: Also, 1 other thing i noticed from the above code is that it only every defines 1 ArrayList data to go into the spinner, whereas I need to combine 3 ArrayLists together.

Comment: Where are you writing the above code ? Ideally it should go in Activity. Have you added Android dependencies in your project. Because you should get ArrayAdapter & setOnItemSelectedListener otherwise.

Comment: For the array list you have to manually create a arraylist which merges 3 array List in simple Java programming. Because Android doesn't provides any such functionality.

Comment: I am adding the code within my onClick function, just above the Log.d("Item","Clicked"); I have imported the ArrayAdapter, but not the setOnItemSelectedListener, what is the library i need to import for this. As for the Array List, I though that might be the case thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I have edited my question, adding your block of code into the onClick function. If you require a bigger breakdown of the whole coding layout let me know. Thanks

Comment: I have edited your code to add the import statement. So, that you get a clear picture as what you have to import. See now if it works.

Comment: Getting closer, have got rid of all the errors, although I did have to change the ArrayAdapter code slightly, changing this to context (see edited code). However, I was having issues with my xml layout, where I had Spinner instead of a Button (app was breaking). Once I  changed this back to Button the Dialog loaded up, however, your Spinner code is still not working, is this due to the layout xml?

Comment: I have edited the code for xml and Activity. Now it should work perfectly.

Comment: Your above code will not work for what I am after, currently the onClick works for the attack Button. I need to add onClick functionality to the spinner button, this is currently what is crashing my app the 'Use Item - Spinner'. Thanks

Comment: Please see my edited code, I have noticed that the application crashed when it hits the spinner.setAdaptor(adp);

Comment: There is no onClick event for the spinner. So you cannot add it on spinner. Spinner only has onItemSelectedListener which i have used in my code. Refer my code, it is working on my machine.

Comment: I have edited my code to add the visibilty functionality. The spinner will be gone as you wanted and then it will be shown after values are set to it. I think all the errors that you are facing is because you want to set click event on spinner.

Comment: I copied your code exactly, however still cannot seem to get it to work, it seems having the spinner in the xml file is breaking the second Dialog call. When changed to Button it is fine (of couse then the rest of the code does not work). I have pasted a more detailed version of my code here - http://pastebin.com/uFbk7hid. This has both Layout xml code and the main Java code for the Dialogs. Hope it is clear. Thanks.

Comment: I still cannot seem to het this to work, using you above code, the only difference is that I have to use context instead of this within the ArrayAdapter!

Comment: Hi ... sorry for the late reply. I am unable to get your requirements.. Can we talk on chat.